# Opening files in eclipse via code

Tags: java, eclipse

I would like to open .java files in Eclipse programatically, i.e. using code to launch Eclipse (if it's not already open) and then opening the specified file.

Basically, something like this (non-working, examplary) code:

```
File file = new File("path/to/file.txt");
EclipseEditor.open(file);
```

Now, I've done a little research and for some time thought I could do this by using `org.eclipse.stuff`, as in [this](https://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_open_an_editor_programmatically%3F) example. However, after some errors trying to even get the required packages/classes on my build path, I now just get an `ExceptionInInitializerError` when I call `EFS.getLocalFileSystem();`.

I'm wondering if these packages might be for eclipse plugins only, and if not, how I could use them as desired.

If they only work with plugins inside an already running eclipse, that's also fine - my application would also be viable as a plugin. I wanted to avoid reading up on how to write plugins, though - so if there is any way to avoid using plugins, I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: See https://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_open_an_editor_programmatically%3F

Comment: I literally linked that in the question ("as in this example"). It doesn't work for me.

Comment: Well, writing an Eclipse plug-in is super easy. Alternatively, you can use [Eclipse EASE](http://www.eclipse.org/ease/) and open the file via JavaScript with `openEditor(file)` (using the `/System/Resources` and the `/System/UI` modules) like in this more complex example, but using [`onStartup`](https://wiki.eclipse.org/EASE/Scripts) as trigger: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40072196/6505250

Comment: Or did you mean open a file in the (maybe running) Eclipse IDE from the command line: [`eclipse --launcher.openFile "path/to/file.txt"`](https://help.eclipse.org/oxygen/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/guide/product_open_file.htm)?

Comment: I'm essentially choosing a list of files that are then modified with regex-match-replace-pairs. Then, I run the tests on those selected files, if they contain any, and those test classes that failed should be opened in Eclipse for manual correction. I suppose using a batch file or something like that would work, but that feels funky :/

Comment: If the manual correction is only needed in some cases, I recommend triggering the command line from Java, from a batch script or from whatever you want. `eclipse --launcher.openFile ...` can also be called with a list of parameters to open several files at once.

Comment: Note that the example you linked to will only run as an Eclipse plugin - you can't use this in a plain Java program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can trigger the command line [`eclipse --launcher.openFile "path/to/file.txt"`](https://help.eclipse.org/oxygen/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/guide/product_open_file.htm) to open one or more files in Eclipse, e. g. via the following Java code:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] {
    "/path/to/eclipse",
    "--launcher.openFile",
    "path/to/file.txt",
    // "path/to/file2.txt",
    // ...
});
```

Alternatively, you can use [Eclipse EASE](http://www.eclipse.org/ease/) from inside of Eclipse and open a file via e. g. JavaScript with `openEditor(file)` (using the `/System/Resources` and the `/System/UI` modules) like in [this more complex example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40072196/6505250).

Comment: thanks, I already implemented your approach! It works as desired :)

Comment: I installed a brand new Eclipse - Version: 2021-06 (4.20.0) Build id: 20210612-2011 - which, on my Mac, gets installed in $HOME/eclipse/java-2021-06/Eclipse.app.  When I start eclipse with:
$HOME/eclipse/java-2021-06/Eclipse.app/Contents/MacOS/eclipse --launcher.openFile /path/to/file
Eclipse opens, but the file does not show (note that I have not created any projects in Eclipse yet - it's a brand new install).

Comment: Commenting on my own comment: apparently I can't open a file because I'm hitting this eclipse bug:
https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=564340